# Install OPENCV 2.4.4 in centos 6.3

Tags: linux, opencv, command, centos, executable

I cannot install OpenCV 2.4.4 in Cent OS 6.3

I have gone here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.4/

Then did:

wget to the direct link available in there to any location in the server with Cent OS 6.3 installed.

After that I did tar xvz CentOS-2.4.4.tar.gz2
then I did cd OpenCV-2.4.4 and then I did cmake ., make, make install

all logged in as root.

Errors I saw from cmake were pythonlibs cannot be found, yet  python 2.7.7 is installed and it seems python 2.6.6 is installed also bundled with Cent OS 6.3 as it shows from cmake that the parser for python is that yet it complains it can't find the pythonlibs.

Asides that I didn't see any other error after cmake.
So I went ahead and did make, waited then did make install

Now I go to the samples directory of OpenCV. cd OpenCV-2.4.4 cd samples cd c
And put the following command in ssh ./myfile.c

which among other things calls a file that comes with opencv, it appear to struggle into finding a file that cannot be found, or a command that can't be found from a broken / wrong install , misconfiguration in the above process / hours of googling to find the answer, etc:

```
 ./facedetect.c: line 5: CvHaarClassifierCascade: command not found
 ./facedetect.c: line 6: CvMemStorage: command not found
 ./facedetect.c: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 ./facedetect.c: line 8: `void detectfaces(IplImage *frame)'
```

CvHaarClassifierCascade
not found

CvMemStorage
not found
what a problem, my OpenCV isn't working on Cent OS 6.3, I can't get it installed.

Also, I am pretty blind on this installation as there is not a single tutorial that I can find to install OpenCV in Cent OS yet there are many tutorials for Ubuntu, else I wouldn't post to stack.

this is the actual error from cmake, with  similar output:

```
 could not find png
 could not find
 tiff
 could not find
 jpeg
 could not find
 jasper
 couldn ot find pythonlibs
 missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH
 no module named numpy.distutils
```

sorry I find the question might be "too localized" - just close it down . thanks

Comment: Regarding python, you might need to install the `python-devel` package.

Answer (score 1):

why struggle when there is readymade linux/centos rpm available for opencv? (with some gotchas but for most part it will be just fine)

Comment: +1 , yes , see [link](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-x86_64/php-facedetect-1.0.0-6.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)